# Настройка httpd.conf

Tags: apache

Не могу настроить httpd.conf. Проблема в том, что апач никак не реагирует на chmod и я не могу получить доступ к файлу даже с правами 777.

**Сам конфиг:**

```
ServerTokens OSServerRoot "/etc/httpd"PidFile run/httpd.pidTimeout 60KeepAlive OffMaxKeepAliveRequests 100KeepAliveTimeout 15<IfModule prefork.c>StartServers       8MinSpareServers    5MaxSpareServers   20ServerLimit      256MaxClients       256MaxRequestsPerChild  4000</IfModule><IfModule itk.c>StartServers       8MinSpareServers    5MaxSpareServers   20ServerLimit      256MaxClients       256MaxRequestsPerChild  4000</IfModule><IfModule worker.c>StartServers         4MaxClients         300MinSpareThreads     25MaxSpareThreads     75 ThreadsPerChild     25MaxRequestsPerChild  0</IfModule>Listen 80LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.soLoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.soLoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.soLoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.soLoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.soLoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.soLoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.soLoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.soLoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.soLoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.soLoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.soLoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.soLoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.soLoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.soLoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.soLoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.soLoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.soLoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.soLoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.soLoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.soLoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.soLoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.soLoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.soLoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.soLoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.soLoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.soLoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.soLoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.soLoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.soLoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.soLoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.soLoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.soLoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.soLoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.soLoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.soLoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.soLoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.soLoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.soLoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.soLoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.soLoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.soLoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.soLoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.soLoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.soLoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.soLoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.soLoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.soLoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.soLoadModule suexec_module modules/mod_suexec.soLoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.soLoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.soLoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.soInclude conf.d/*.confUser apacheGroup apacheServerAdmin root@localhostUseCanonicalName OffDocumentRoot "/var/www/html"<Directory />    Options FollowSymLinks    AllowOverride None</Directory><Directory "/var/www/html">    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks AllowOverride All    Order allow,deny    Allow from all</Directory><IfModule mod_userdir.c>    UserDir disabled</IfModule>DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.varAccessFileName .htaccess<Files ~ "^\.ht">    Order allow,deny    Deny from all    Satisfy All</Files>TypesConfig /etc/mime.typesDefaultType text/plain<IfModule mod_mime_magic.c>MIMEMagicFile conf/magic</IfModule>HostnameLookups OffErrorLog logs/error_logLogLevel warnLogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combinedLogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" commonLogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" refererLogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agentCustomLog logs/access_log combinedServerSignature OnAlias /icons/ "/var/www/icons/"<Directory "/var/www/icons">    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks    AllowOverride None    Order allow,deny    Allow from all</Directory><IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>    DAVLockDB /var/lib/dav/lockdb</IfModule>ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">    AllowOverride None    Options None    Order allow,deny    Allow from all</Directory>IndexOptions FancyIndexing VersionSort NameWidth=* HTMLTable Charset=UTF-8AddIconByEncoding (CMP,/icons/compressed.gif) x-compress x-gzipAddIconByType (TXT,/icons/text.gif) text/*AddIconByType (IMG,/icons/image2.gif) image/*AddIconByType (SND,/icons/sound2.gif) audio/*AddIconByType (VID,/icons/movie.gif) video/*AddIcon /icons/binary.gif .bin .exeAddIcon /icons/binhex.gif .hqxAddIcon /icons/tar.gif .tarAddIcon /icons/world2.gif .wrl .wrl.gz .vrml .vrm .ivAddIcon /icons/compressed.gif .Z .z .tgz .gz .zipAddIcon /icons/a.gif .ps .ai .epsAddIcon /icons/layout.gif .html .shtml .htm .pdfAddIcon /icons/text.gif .txtAddIcon /icons/c.gif .cAddIcon /icons/p.gif .pl .pyAddIcon /icons/f.gif .forAddIcon /icons/dvi.gif .dviAddIcon /icons/uuencoded.gif .uuAddIcon /icons/script.gif .conf .sh .shar .csh .ksh .tclAddIcon /icons/tex.gif .texAddIcon /icons/bomb.gif coreAddIcon /icons/back.gif ..AddIcon /icons/hand.right.gif READMEAddIcon /icons/folder.gif ^^DIRECTORY^^AddIcon /icons/blank.gif ^^BLANKICON^^DefaultIcon /icons/unknown.gifReadmeName README.htmlHeaderName HEADER.htmlIndexIgnore .??* *~ *# HEADER* README* RCS CVS *,v *,tAddLanguage ca .caAddLanguage cs .cz .csAddLanguage da .dkAddLanguage de .deAddLanguage el .elAddLanguage en .enAddLanguage eo .eoAddLanguage es .esAddLanguage et .etAddLanguage fr .frAddLanguage he .heAddLanguage hr .hrAddLanguage it .itAddLanguage ja .jaAddLanguage ko .koAddLanguage ltz .ltzAddLanguage nl .nlAddLanguage nn .nnAddLanguage no .noAddLanguage pl .poAddLanguage pt .ptAddLanguage pt-BR .pt-brAddLanguage ru .ruAddLanguage sv .svAddLanguage zh-CN .zh-cnAddLanguage zh-TW .zh-twLanguagePriority en ca cs da de el eo es et fr he hr it ja ko ltz nl nn no pl pt pt-BR ru sv zh-CN zh-TWForceLanguagePriority Prefer FallbackAddDefaultCharset UTF-8AddType application/x-compress .ZAddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgzAddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crtAddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crlAddHandler type-map varAddType text/html .shtmlAddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtmlAlias /error/ "/var/www/error/"<IfModule mod_negotiation.c><IfModule mod_include.c>    <Directory "/var/www/error">    AllowOverride None    Options IncludesNoExec    AddOutputFilter Includes html    AddHandler type-map var    Order allow,deny    Allow from all    LanguagePriority en es de fr    ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback    </Directory><Directory /var/www/*/data/>php_admin_flag engine off</Directory></IfModule></IfModule>BrowserMatch "Mozilla/2" nokeepaliveBrowserMatch "MSIE 4\.0b2;" nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0BrowserMatch "RealPlayer 4\.0" force-response-1.0    BrowserMatch "Java/1\.0" force-response-1.0BrowserMatch "JDK/1\.0" force-response-1.0BrowserMatch "Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider" redirect-carefullyBrowserMatch "MS FrontPage" redirect-carefullyBrowserMatch "^WebDrive" redirect-carefullyBrowserMatch "^WebDAVFS/1.[0123]" redirect-carefullyBrowserMatch "^gnome-vfs/1.0" redirect-carefullyBrowserMatch "^XML Spy" redirect-carefullyBrowserMatch "^Dreamweaver-WebDAV-SCM1" redirect-carefullyInclude /usr/local/ispmgr/etc/ispmgr.inc<Directory /var/www/bh48647/data/www/ga-realtor.ru>Options -Includes -ExecCGIphp_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/bh48647/data:."php_admin_flag engine on</Directory><Directory /var/www/bh48647/data/www/kak-mne-bistro-pohudet.ru>Options -Includes -ExecCGIphp_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/bh48647/data:."php_admin_flag engine on</Directory><Directory /var/www/bh48647/data/www/thevkontakte.ru>Options +ExecCGI -Includesphp_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/bh48647/data:."php_admin_flag engine on</Directory><Directory /var/www/bh48647/data/www/all-mob.ru>Options +ExecCGI -Includesphp_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/bh48647/data:."php_admin_flag engine on</Directory><Directory /var/www/bh48647/data/www/rabochaya-dieta.ru>Options -ExecCGI -Includesphp_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/bh48647/data:."php_admin_flag engine on</Directory><Directory /var/www/bh48647/data/www/i-doser.ru>Options -ExecCGI -Includesphp_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/bh48647/data:."php_admin_flag engine on</Directory><Directory /var/www/bh48647/data/www/leondays.ru>Options +ExecCGI -Includesphp_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/bh48647/data:."php_admin_flag engine on</Directory><Directory /var/www/bh48647/data/www/tomypage.ru>Options +ExecCGI -Includesphp_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/bh48647/data:."php_admin_flag engine on</Directory><Directory /var/www/bh48647/data/www/onlinediscountshop.ru>Options +ExecCGI -Includesphp_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/bh48647/data:."php_admin_flag engine on</Directory><Directory /var/www/bh48647/data/www/rumetalgroup.ru>Options +ExecCGI -Includesphp_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/bh48647/data:."php_admin_flag engine on</Directory>NameVirtualHost 162.247.14.134:80NameVirtualHost 162.247.14.134:80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что по поводу safemode в файле php.ini?

А также в php.ini нет ли в запрете команды chmod в параметре disable_function

Так как запуск chmod из скрипта можно запускать только через php, а значит надо настраивать php.ini файл, и после каждого изменения файла перезапускать аппачи.